# How can I make the exterior of my croissants less hard and more flaky?

Tags: baking, bread

My croissants look good and they taste fine but they have an extremely flaky/hard exterior, it is like a biscuit even though they are light in weight and have the bee caves inside as supposed. I would like to have the one that is really flaky but not toasted.

I use

- 2 cups of bread flour
- 2.5 tsp active dry yeast
- 2.5 tbsp sugar
- 1.5 tsp salt
- 1.5 tbsp of butter inside the dough
- 1/2 cup of milk
- 1/2 cup of water

I knead it long enough and then I leave it to chill overnight. The next day, I place butter slab, make 3 simple layers with 15 minutes freezing in between, and finally let them chill for the last time for 1 hour plus in refrigerator before I shape them and let them proof for 2 hours at room temperature. I bake them at 400F for 10 minutes and at 370F for another 10 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

this is a technique that **might help** with the shell issue:

I suspect your croissants are **losing humidity** during proofing, possibly freezing the butter block, and possibly baking resulting in a harder shell.  If you have a humidity controlled proofer and oven, then those parts may not be your problem.  Otherwise, read on:

Peter Reinhart in The Bread Baker's Apprentice suggests pouring **boiling water in a flat pan**/container and placing in the bottom of the oven during the baking (of breads) in order to keep up the humidity.  [This  Link](http://bewitchingkitchen.com/tag/peter-reinhart-croissants/) has the recipe published with Peter's permission.  Notice how the freezer doesn't come into play (freezer is a dehydrator and pretty good at it, too) although some recipes call the freezing part *a must*.

Croissants are lighter than bread loafs so they may require a different humidity profile than breads during baking (as noted by commenters). However, for proofing humidity levels should be high and the temperature around 80F or 27C.

To achieve that, for the **proofing** period keep the dough in a turned-off-oven and turn on the oven light a long with a the boiling water method.  This usually prevents 'the skin' formation and a dried out crust.  It also helps with getting a better rise during baking.  The oven light bumps up the temperature but if you're room temperature is close, don't bother.

You may wish to read [this piece](http://www.classofoods.com/page2_3.html) on humidity and baking and generally the [Maillard Reaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maillard_reaction).  Here's an excerpt that might explain the problem:

```
"Under dry oven conditions, the dough will have rapid evaporation of the water from
the exposed surface. This will cause premature formation of a dry inelastic outer shell
on the bread surface"
```

Comment: Humidity during baking actually *contributes* to crust development.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ citation please.  the main suggestion here is 2-hour at room temperature might dry the shell.  Though, Peter suggests humidity in baking (as noted).  I do see the 1000 daily croissants at our french baker protected from drying, though I've never walked in at 4AM to see the oven settings.

Comment: http://baking911.com/quick-guide/how-to-az/bread-get-good-crust  This was just the first hit on google, but they have the core of it.  Moisture in the proof box yes, but in the oven, steam helps promote crust development.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ first hit on google? I know you can do better.  humidity contributes to crust colour, not thickness.  Here is the piece you want to read: ["Under dry oven conditions, the dough will have rapid evaporation of the water from the exposed surface. This will cause premature formation of a dry inelastic outer shell on the bread surface"](http://www.classofoods.com/page2_3.html)

Comment: @MandoMando- Steam in the oven also promotes expansion per your link but it causes gelatinization of the starches at the surface of the loaf producing a crisper crust. It is steam that makes the characteristic crispy crust on French bread. I don't know how it would effect croissants though. I'm at work and don't have my books available to prove it.

Comment: @Sobachatina right, can't guarantee which effect will take dominance in croissant's case given the size, layers of fat, and the nearly hollow, low moisture, center.  For the purpose of OP's question, however, the answer is mostly focused on keeping moisture pre-baking time while not ruling out the baking part. That should serve to improve on the issue OP has raised.

Comment: alright, i ve tried the boiling water container while baking twice and i got crispier results.

Comment: @RibalDhaibi great, that settles that part. Did you try the high humidity proofing?

Comment: no Mando i didn't try the humidity proofing that you ve mentioned earlier, I also use the (off) oven for proofing though but I didn't try to place a boiling water container in. i will try in my next batch and also I will split the batch in 2, some to go for humid proofing and the rest to chill for 15 minutes in freezer prior to baking as dnozy mentioned, both worth a try. btw, may adding an egg to the dough help somehow? i ve seen an Australian guy who added eggs to the croissants on youtube, here is the link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvYMnMT6eVc

Comment: @RibalDhaibi well croissant is halfway between puff pastry and brioche (which has eggs), so you _could_ use an egg. By the same token you could use all milk (3/4 total). I'm assuming you are egg glazing before rise and once more (gently) before baking. Did you see my comment on the butter? 12Tbs vs 1.5? That's a big jump.

Comment: for some reason i could not locate your comment on the butter! sorry, but hope you will be able to repost it next

Comment: @RibalDhaibi I've moved it here from below the question: "can you verify the butter amount? The equivalent recipe from The Bread Bible calls for 12tablespoons of highfat butter."

Comment: inside the dough i add 1.5 tbsp of butter and for the slab i use 8 tbsp of butter which is one block, again that is for 2 cups of bread flour or 500g

Comment: @RibalDhaibi that's consistent with Peter's.  Although both Peter and the Bread Bible suggest using all-purpose four instead of bread flour (less protein yields softer).

Comment: thank you Mando for your advice, I definitely will try also all purpose flour soon, and I am hopping for better results.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a croissant expert, but it's worth a try.

Do the same thing you have done before but:

- proof the croissants
- chill the croissants for 15min in the freezer
- bake

You can also try to use a lower temperature;
I have seen some recipes that call for 15 - 20min at 350F.